# Bootstrap's Normalize overriding Boostrap.min.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

*To clarify - I'm not trying to override Bootstrap styles with custom css.*

I'm working on converting some web pages that use tables into the Vue framework.  I noticed that the table styling (I am using Bootstrap 3.4.1) in the Vue version on my local host is missing a padding of 8px that exists in the non Vue version I'm migrating from.

In devtools, the non Vue version has

```
.table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, 
.table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, 
.table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td { padding:8px
```

whereas in the new Vue version I see `td, th { padding:0px`.  (This also appears in the non Vue version but is strikethrough).

The former appears to come from `bootstrap.min.css`, the latter from `normalize.less` within Bootstrap's node_modules folder. (I used `npm`)  In my `main.js` file, I have (in this order)

```
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "@/css/bootstrap-theme.css";
```

and I am not importing any form of `normalize.css`

How do I specify I want the `tables.less` styling as opposed to the `normalize` styling?

EDIT: What is further confusing me is that I have other webpages in the same project where tables exist and are being formatted as desired, so I know I'm importing Bootstrap correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include a `<tbody>` tag!